# Send DbConnection via OperationContract in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dbconnection, operationcontract

Is there any possibility to send DbConnection as a parameter of OperationConstract in WCF? Because I get exception "Type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection with data contract name SqlConnection:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.SqlClient. is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is never going to work. A `SqlConnection` is a wrapper around a local connection which only makes sense in that one `AppDomain`, in that one process, on that one machine. At best you could send the connection string, but that doesn't guarantee that the other user *can* connect (line-of-sight to the server / firewalls, the account identity, etc).

Frankly I would find it questionable to *want* to do that. A service should expose *data*, not internal mechanics like internal connections.